# Why does omission of "#include <string>" only sometimes cause compilation failures?

Tags: c++, string, include

I am a beginner with C++. When I write the code sometimes I write `#include <string>` and the code works, other times I don't write `#include <string>` and the code doesn't work. But sometimes it works without `#include <string>`.

So do I have to write `#include <string>` so that the code works?

Comment: People, what the hell?! Of course this is a real, legitimate question! Where do all the downvotes and close votes come from? Go back to bed.

Comment: Somehow, in my mind, this question was as effective as `these are not the droids you are looking for`.

Comment: The question could've been better posed but when they start off with "I am a beginner with C++" it's safe to assume they may not entirely understand how includes work and leave a comment instead of a close or down vote.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you use members that are declared inside the standard header `string` then yes, you have to include that header either directly or indirectly (via other headers).

*Some* compilers on *some* platforms may on *some* time of the month compile even though you failed to include the header. This behaviour is unfortunate, unreliable and does not mean that you shouldn’t include the header.

The reason is simply that you have included other standard headers which *also* happen to include `string`. But as I said, this can in general not be relied on and it may also change very suddenly (when a new version of the compiler is installed, for instance).

Always include all necessary headers. Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a reliable online documentation on which headers need to be included. Consult a book, or the official C++ standard.

For instance, the following code compiles with my compiler (`gcc` 4.6):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str;
}
```

But if I remove the first line, it no longer compiles even though the `iostream` header should actually be unrelated.

Comment: Any idea whether it happens with header files other than `<string>`?

Comment: @C.R. It definitely does, obviously, since the standard headers sometimes use each other. For instance, `std::pair` is defined in `<utility>` yet there is *no* implementation of the standard library which requires you to include this header if you’ve already included `<map>` since the latter requires `std::pair`. The same is true for other types as well. This is incidentally one of the big weaknesses of the C++ header system as compared to a proper module system.

Comment: Regarding *Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a reliable online documentation on which headers need to be included.* you can always search for what you are using on cppreference.com and it will tell you the header it is in.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, they now document this rigorously. Previous versions didn’t. cppreference.com is nowadays my #1 go-to reference.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible that *other* headers that you **do** include have `#include <string>` in them.

Nonetheless, it is usually a good idea to `#include <string>` directly in your code even if not strictly necessary for a successful build, in case these "other" headers change - for example because of a different (or different version of) compiler / standard library implementation, platform or even just a build configuration.

*(Of course, this discussion applies to any header, not just `<string>`.)*

Answer (score 3):

Although, there is no *direct* occurence of `#include <string>` in a particular source file, doesn't mean it hasn't been included by another header file. Consider this:

File: `header.h`

```
#if !defined(__HEADER_H__)
#define __HEADER_H__

// more here
#include <string>
// ...and here

#endif
```

File: `source1.cc`

```
#include <string>

void foo()
{
    // No error here.
    string s = "Foo";
}
```

File: `source2.cc`

```
#include <header.h>

void bar()
{
    // Still no error, since there's a #include <string> in header.h
    string s = "Bar";
}
```

File: `source3.cc`

```
void zoid()
{
    // Here's the error; no such thing as "string", since non of the
    // previous headers had been included.
    string s = "Zoid";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using a pointer/reference to a user defined type, the type only needs to be declared:

```
class my_class;
void foo(const my_class& c);
```

But when you're using the value, the compiler needs to know the size and with that the definition of the type.

And keep in mind that standard headers may include other ones, which doesn't automaticly mean that all implementations do that, so you can't rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not true that the header string is included by other headers. The header string itself only has includes. No Definitions. So all necessary definitions needed for the usage of string are in headers included by the header string. These headers may already be included by other headers. Then everything works. The header ios for example includes stringbuf, which includes ...

Answer (score 0):

Even though you haven't explicitly included string, it has been included because of another standard header you included. For example vector may have included string. When you include vector, every thing from vector will get included in your file.

I think future versions of Cpp should have a include_module or module keyword; which only include a specific module from a file. So if a file has 3 classes we only include the one we need.

for example
  -I "../mingw/lib/include"

```
 module <string>
```

Searches the directory for files that define string class. Compilation would be signicantly slower.

Answer (score 0):

As Branko said:

> It is possible that other headers that you do include have #include  in them.

Let's take a look at `iostream` includes:

```
#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
```

if you check `istream` you can see some `include`
so like this, we have:

> iostream => istream => ios => iosfwd

and in `iosfwd` we have string library! but it's not standard, it's for forward declaration. in `iosfwd` we have:

> #include <bits/stringfwd.h>   // For string forward declarations.

and in `stringfwd.h`:

> ```
> @file bits/stringfwd.h
> This is an internal header file, included by other library headers.
> Do not attempt to use it directly. @headername{string}
> ```

so, You can use `string` without `#include <string>`.