# C++ template method in header file

Tags: c++, templates

I'm having a problem with the following code:

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>


namespace Utils
{
    template<class T> 
    std::string hexify(T val)
    {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "0x"
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T) * 2)
            << std::hex << val;
        return stream.str();
    }
};

#endif
```

It tells me that "'setw': identifier not found", and the same for every std:: function call.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: `#include <iomanip>`

Comment: Check e.g. [this I/O manipulator reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip).

Comment: [std::setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Comment: Why do you think it has anything to do with having a function template in a header?

Comment: BTW it seems like you're also using `std::string` and `std::stringstream` without the required includes (`<string>` and `<sstream>`).  See cppreference.com for more info.

Comment: ah so sorry guys, I had the missing includes (without noticing) in the cpp file before I moved the template functions into the .h file. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set field width** (setw) belongs to `<iomanip>` which you've not included in your code apparently. Try this code :

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>     

namespace Utils
{
    template<class T> 
    std::string hexify(T val)
    {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "0x"
            << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(sizeof(T) * 2)
            << std::hex << val;
        return stream.str();
    }
};

#endif
```

for more info : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setw/

Comment: `stringstream` also needs an include.

Comment: Also, sometimes cppreference.com is more accurate than cplusplus.com ...

Comment: @KonradRudolph check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539650/why-does-omission-of-include-string-only-sometimes-cause-compilation-failur

Comment: @ÅdəəlÅhmåd What’s your point? The code is invalid. It may happen to work but it’s invalid. Incidentally, the linked question was answered *by me*, and you should read that answer.

Comment: If your top most comment is a suggestion , then yup i agree, but this chunk of code is working so inclusion of stringstream is not necessary. that is my point. still respect your opinion so editing my answer .

Comment: It isn't a matter of opinion. Without the necessary includes your code can be considered to be broken.