# C++ Error (operand types are 'std::string and 'void')

Tags: c++, class, object

1st of all Im newBee at C++ programming.so please apologize if i make lots of mistake while asking questions.

**My problem is**:

i create class which contain private variable and Methods like below:

```
class Records{

private:
    string name;
public:
    string n;

    void setValue(){
          cout << "Enter name" << endl;
          cin >> name;
     }

    void getValue(){
         n = name;
        cout << "Name is: " <<  n << endl;
    }

};
```

Comment: The problem is not in the code that you posted - please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I have **run** your code on **GCC compiler**, it's successfully worked. Please, see complete example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Records{

        private:
                string name;
        public:
                string n;

                void setValue(){
                        cout << "Enter name" << endl;
                        cin >> name;
                }

                void getValue(){
                        n = name;
                        cout << "Name is: " <<  n << endl;
                }
};

int main()
{
        Records r;
        r.setValue();
        r.getValue();
}
```

Comment: Your example is wrong, as you did not `#include <string>`.  [See here](http://rextester.com/FUMZ20262)

Comment: [Please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539650/why-does-omission-of-include-string-only-sometimes-cause-compilation-failur)

Comment: Yes, but it depend on compilers.

Comment: And when / if gcc changes the way they organize the headers, then what?  If you're using `<string>` then it should be included.  Not doing so just leads to bad habits.

Comment: Please, open tutorial point and open gcc compiler, then copy this code and run it.

Comment: Ummn.  No.  It doesn't matter what the compiler is doing *now*.  Did you read the link to the SO question?  You're risking a downvote.