# Compiling without all header files being included and giving output too

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have been trying to use Visual Studio to run my C++ codes, but I couldn't find a way around it. I came across this extension called [C/C++ Compile Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=danielpinto8zz6.c-cpp-compile-run), which was simple to use. I also use the standard [C/C++ Microsoft Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools).

I then tried it out by running this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hello";
    char x[10];
    cout<<"\nEnter a string please: ";
    gets(x);
    puts(x);
}
```

I forgot to include `stdio.h`, but the code compiled successfully with the C/C++ Compile Run extension. It gave this output:

> ```
> hello
> Enter a string please: string
> string
> ```

But, I didn't include `stdio.h`. Is there any way to fix this? Or should I try another way of compiling my C++ code?

Comment: Standard library headers may themselves include other headers. You are just not guaranteed what they include with any given impletation.

Comment: Headers can include other headers. You can't count in it, but `iostream` may well be including the other headers you require.

Comment: `stdio.h` gets included indirectly. Don't count on such behavior. Include the appropriate standard header file for the functions you are using. That will keep your code clean.

Comment: Haven't found a general duplicate, but [Why does omission of “#include <string>” only sometimes cause compilation failures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539650/why-does-omission-of-include-string-only-sometimes-cause-compilation-failur) is pretty close

Comment: If you are working on Linux, just go to this path **/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/** and visit **iostream** header file. It includes **c++config.h** file which include other c header file and goes on. As mentioned in above comments, it's always good to include your required header files explicitly.

Comment: Is there any way I can prevent it from being included directly? I mean, it'd be useful if I forget to include any in the future.

Comment: Not really. The including header probably is written in such a way that it will not function without the included header and headers should be complete entities, including everything they need to prevent other (often worse) families of errors.