# Can Apples gcc be made compatible to GNUs gcc C/C++ code?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, darwin, apple-developer

I'm trying to build a [C/C++ project](https://git.maxr.org/maxr/maxr) on my mac. Unfortunately it does not compile with Apples gcc:

```
In file included from /src/connectionmanager.cpp:20:
/src/network.h:98:14: error: implicit instantiation of undefined
      template 'std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      std::__1::allocator<char> >'
        std::string connectToIp;
                    ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iosfwd:193:32: note: template is declared here
    class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS basic_string;
                               ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/maxr.dir/src/connectionmanager.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/maxr.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

With GNU gcc version 9.1.0 all source files compile without a problem, but unfortunately cannot be linked by Apples linker.

Are there some compatibility flags for Apples gcc to make it accept code that GNUs gcc compiles without a problem?

This is the Apple gcc version:

```
$ gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: `network.h` is missing `#include <string>`.

Comment: For an explanation of why there might be different behaviours with different compilers, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539650/why-does-omission-of-include-string-only-sometimes-cause-compilation-failur).