# use of undeclared identifier make_tuple

Tags: c++, tuples

This is the very start of my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>

const int NR_TREES = 100;
const int R = 50;
const int RI = 35;
const int RC = 15;

using namespace std;

float oldX, oldY;
float cameraAlfa, cameraBeta;
float cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ;
float dirX, dirY, dirZ;

vector<tuple<float, float>> treePoints;


void populateTrees(){
    srand(clock());

    for(int i = 0; i < NR_TREES; i++){
        float x = (float) (rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX/200)) - 100;
        float y = (float) (rand()) / ((float) (RAND_MAX/200)) - 100;

        if(x * x + y * y > R * R){
        treePoints.push_back(make_tuple(x, y)); //problem here
        }
        else{
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I try to compile it says "use of undeclared identifier make_tuple", even thought in the vector declaration it works with tuple perfectly fine. I honestly have no idea...
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  You forgot to include `<tuple>`.  You **must** always include the headers you use functions from.

Comment: For why, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539650/why-does-omission-of-include-string-only-sometimes-cause-compilation-failur

Comment: Well that works, but I thought make tuple was from std?

Comment: Thank you, didnt know the difference between using functions and the type itslef

Comment: @PedroFernandes This has noting to do with functions vs types. You *always* have to include the correct header for *everything* from`std::` that you are using.

Comment: Well yhea, but I can use the tuple name without including it...

Comment: @PedroFernandes See the linked duplicate. You *must* include `<tuple>` to use `std::tuple`. It *may* work without that, but this is not guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

Needed to include tuple. Was confused because tuple itself is in std

Comment: The reasoning of this answer makes no sense, see comment under question.